# How to read variables declared in .scss files in to d3 charts

Tags: d3.js, sass

I have multiple variables declared in .scss file i want to read same variables in to my d3 charts
ex:

`$body-color: #424656;`

```
    d3.select(…)
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", line(data))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
```

for example in above code i want to change stroke color as per my .sccs variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
.attr("fill", var(--body-color)